# Enabling and Disabling Button in asp.net c# code behind and javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have two buttons Save and Register . I want to enable/disable these buttons based on Two Functions.The first function is a javascript function.The second function works on another button click event .Both functions are working perfectly . But my problem is when the javascript fuction works the Save button is enabled and Register button is disabled . During my button click event Register button is enabled and Save button is disabled . This works perfectly during first time .During second time when again I call the javascript function , previously enabled or disabled buttons doesn't change . Someone please help me .Any help will be really appreciated.

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function exists()
{
    document.getElementById("<%= but_Register.ClientID %>").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("<%= btn_save.ClientID %>").style.visibility = "";
}
</script>
```

C# :

```
protected void btn_newrgstr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    but_Register.Visible = true;
    btn_save.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Are you using `UpdatePanel`s?

Comment: @FF- YES ..these buttons are inside updatepanel .

Answer (score 0):

According to your code you're not enabling/disabling buttons but show/hide those.
While the javascript function (`exists`) works on client side and change button visibility on client side, the `btn_newrgstr_Click` function is on server side and actually causes not visible button not being rendered to client. As a result your client side function won't be able to find this button.
One way to solve this, is not to use `xxx.Visible = false` on server side, but instead set control style.